# Using powershell to flip web sites

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'm trying to use PowerShell with IE object to load two different sites back and forth.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.visible = $true
while ($ie.busy) {sleep -milliseconds 50}
while($i -lt 10)
{
   $i++
   $ie.navigate("http://www.google.com")
   sleep -s 10
   $ie.navigate("http://www.microsoft.com")
   sleep -s 10
}
```

Basically, I want load the browser, navigate to google, wait 10 seconds, navigate to Microsoft, wait 10 seconds, and loop that 10 times.

When I run it now, the page loads up, and navigates fine the first time, but then start popping "**Method invocation failed because [System._ComObject] doesn't contain a method named 'navigate'**." over and over.

I can't find anything in the documentation explaining how to do this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post the code for `maxIE`, as I am able to run it fine when not calling that method

Comment: Sorry, I took maxIE out, it just set height and width of the page.

Comment: @Serge Is one of them in your Trusted Sites list, or in a different IE security zone? Once you hit a site like that, IE loads it in a new process which is not connected to your COM object anymore and your COM object stops working. If so, http://stackoverflow.com/q/18117322/478656 might have answers.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - thanks for the reply.  They're actually both internal pages, and both in the trusted zone.  I just google and microsoft for the sake of the example.  I'll see if I can follow this thought and see if that's the reason.