# PowerShell Save IE Webpage Text

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

I'd like to save a webpage (ASP) exactly as IE would save it as a text file.

I found [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/95ce08b7-20cc-4ff8-9311-8aa5e6f81782/save-webpage-as-mhthtml-file-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) and tried:

```
$ie=New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.Navigate($Page)
$ie.Document.execCommand("SaveAs", $false, "1.txt")
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:3 char:1
+ $ie.Document.execCommand("SaveAs", $false, "1.txt")
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

If I try to capture the page via

```
$web = New-Object Net.WebClient
$web | Get-Member
$web.DownloadString($Page) | Out-File "test.html"
```

I get a page, but it's an error page created by the site letting me know the link is invalid, so it only actually finds the page if I load it through an IE session.

I really just need to automate capturing the IE page as a text file, and I'm hoping to do it without using the `SendKey` function.  Can anyone assist?

Comment: Possibly you're not waiting for IE to finish loading the page and parse the HTML and generate a DOM, so there is no .Document yet. You typically want to `.Navigate(..)` and then `while ($ie.Busy -or $ie.ReadyState -ne 4) { start-sleep -Milliseconds 100 }` to wait for it to load the content, before doing anything with it.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe that's it, but right now it's running/hanging.  Shouldn't it only be 1/10th a second delay with that?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I also tried a `Start-Sleep 10` between navigate and execCommand, but got the same error.  Adding the line you suggest still just hangs forever.  Ideas?

Comment: Right now it's running? What happened to the `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.` ?  It won't be a 1/10th of a second delay, it will be an endless delay because it's in a loop until IE reports it's finished.

Comment: idea: you're navigating to a "trusted site", IE is reloading it in a new protected mode process and your `$ie` com object no longer points to anything?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That's probably what's happening.  It opens in a separate window and it's an internal page.  Any idea how to work around that?  Can I snag the PID and point to that or something?

Comment: You can possibly use the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117322/powershell-web-page-automation-works-on-internet-not-intranet

Comment: Thanks.  I'll check into that tomorrow.

Comment: Why don't you check `if ($ie.busy)` and then put the sleep accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Try Invoke-WebRequest:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://www.powershell.org" -OutFile "powershell.txt"
```